# Request part (not all) of a JSON or XML object?

Tags: ajax, xml, json, d3.js

I'm planning a D3.js application that will display a network graph (i.e. display nodes and edges--not a line plot or barchart, etc.).  Only some nodes and edges need to be displayed at any given moment, and the attributes of nodes and edges will change, too--all in response to user interaction.  So far, so good--I know that d3.js can do this sort of thing, as illustrated by the [force-collapsible example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html) and the [health and wealth of nations example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations).  It would be simplest to keep all of the data in a single JSON or XML object.

I'm worried that if my application loads all of the data needed for all parts of the network at any time, I'll overwhelm the user's system.  A typical network will have 35000 nodes, with attributes that vary at up to 5000 timesteps.  (This is about 4GB in a GEXF format XML file with unnecessary whitespace removed.)

Is there a way to request only part of a JSON or XML object, i.e. only those parts of the tree that I need a given time?  Or will I have to do something more complicated? Any pointers to options to investigate will be appreciated.

(This might be FAQ, but it's one of those things that's difficult to search on.)

Comment: 2 solutions. You can implement on server side with DB query so that the response to ajax request provides (1) json/xml data just necessary for given time (2)  json/xml data corresponding to the difference data between previous time and current time.

Comment: Thanks @hitokun_s.  That sounds perfect.  So I can keep all of the data in a single json or xml object, which--on the client side--has pieces of it that are so far unexamined?

Comment: What do you mean by 'all of the data in a single json or xml object' ? If it means a data-source on server side, the answer is yes.